# My API Stripe keys not working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments, figaro-ruby

I have an app where i am trying to integrate stripe api. While following a certain tutorial i managed to configure my stripe keys as shown below.

In config/application.yml (figaro)

```
development:
  stripe_secret_key: sk_test_******************
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_******************

production:
  stripe_secret_key: sk_test_******************
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_******************
```

Then in config/initializers/stripe.rb i have

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['stripe_publishable_key'],
    :secret_key      => ENV['stripe_secret_key']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Everything works fine in development, however, when i deploy my app to heroku i get the error "You did not set a valid publishable key". Can someone advise, what is it i am doing wrong? I am still working with test mode.

Comment: The production or live key should starts with `pk_live_xxx` and `sk_live_xxxx`. probably that's the problem.

Comment: I have not yet tried with live stripe keys. I am using the test keys because i want to make sure i get it right before working in live mode or are you saying the test keys only work in development ?

Comment: I see. Sorry my bad, what you could do is to print your key out before 
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key] making sure you are passing the correct environment settings/configurations. 
Looks like a configuration is not picked up